# Counting the frequency of unique entries in an excel column

Tags: excel

I run a customer service department (I'm new to this so need to learn quickly) and I'm trying to get some analytics on our customer service requests. I have a table in excel documenting every individual service request and I would like a graph showing the total number of requests per customer. [image: Table 1]

I could write this manually (see below) but I would like it to automatically update as more service requests are entered.

[image: Example table]

I have tried looking for answers to this but can't find any that update automatically or that don't require a table elsewhere to be manually updated with each new customer. We often get new customers and I dont want to have to go back to this every time to update a reference table or customer list.

Surely there must be a way in excel to "Count all entries of each occurrence of a name in a column" in some kind of smart way?

I would really appreciate help with this!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be clear, COUNTIF wouldn't work as it requires typing in the name of a customer and I want this graph to update automatically or just by clicking recalculate when a new customer (not on the list before) is added. I can't see how a PivotTable would help either as the data I would need to plot is not something that would go in the primary table, it would need to be calculated from it by counting the frequency of each customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 365 you could take advantage of spilled ranges.

- On your second image put `=UNIQUE(Table1[Customer])` in cell `B3`.
- Put `=COUNTIF(Table1[Customer],B3#)` in cell `C3` - this formula will
  spill to all your unique customers.

Create two names ranges:

- One called `XAxis` which references `=Sheet1!$B$3#`
- One called `ChartValues` which references `=Sheet1!$C$3#`

Create your chart:

- Set series value to `=Sheet1!ChartValues`
- Set axis to `=Sheet1!XAxis`

Change `Sheet1` to whatever your sheet is called remembering to wrap with `'` if it has a space in the name.

Comment: This is great! almost got it to work, When I use "UNIQUE" outside a table, it displays all the names properly, but as soon as I put that in a table, I get #SPILL!. It is counting the frequency correctly though. How do I get it to populate each row with the subsequent name in the Spill range it has calculated? I could avoid using a table, but then I don't get the count column to automatically update either

Comment: Unfortunately [spilled array formulas aren't supported in Excel tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/-spill-error-table-formula-8bfa1758-1be4-42f4-a974-c4d4bc513d4b).  But `=UNIQUE(Table1[Customer])` will always reference the whole raw data table column and `B3#` will reference the whole (unique) spilled range so your count will always include any new rows in the raw data - including new customers.

Comment: Brilliant! that works exactly how I wanted it to! It is updating every time I add a new customer! I had been trying to add the UNIQUE function inside a table, but with the use of # in the cell reference it automatically ranges it for you so you don't need a table! how clever!

Answer (score 1):

**Better to use pivot tables.**

If below is your data,

[image]

- Go to **Insert** > **PivotTable**

  - A popup will show like below

    [image]
  - Specify the Table/Range
  - Specify also the Location (anywhere in the Existing Worksheet)
  - The view below will be displayed

    [image]
- Click the Customer checkbox and also drag the Customer field to fill the VALUES box as shown in the image below

  [image]

  - You desired table will be displayed as below

    [image]

**Please vote up if okay.**

Comment: Is the only way to do this with an additional column in the original table that counts the occurrence of each customer name then? I'm very surprised excel doesn't have a function to count this stuff without having to write it to a new column. It will mean that each row will have duplicated data if another entry from the same customer is in the table. (i.e. each row from A will have "3" in it if there are 3 entries from A). The new column would have to contain "COUNTIF(Table1[Customer],Table1[Customer])" so then I could do the pivot table idea. But it feels redundant making this new column.

Comment: First you need a unique list of customers. How do you intend to do this? Since this can be done easily by PivotTable?

Comment: You can put any existing column in the values area and count it - eg your 'service no' column

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, I got what I was looking for. I ended up adding a column in my initial table called "1" and it just contained the number 1 for each row then I hid the column. Then when I made a pivot table of "Customer" and "1", it gave me the number of entries each customer has. Genuinely disappointed Excel can't do something this basic behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your suggestions. I found a solution from multiple answers and comments.

I ended up going to my original table that I am using to create new service records. I added a column called "1" and just entered the number 1 in that column, for every row. I then "Hid" this column in the usual fashion.

I then created a pivot table from this table and selected to display columns "Customer" and "1" and used these columns to produce a bar graph. Here is the result (With the column "1" unhidden):

[image]

tl;dr:
Excel is unable to do this in any smart way, create a column in the original table contianing the number 1 so when a pivot table is made, it will auto sum the 1's for entries from the same customer. Create a plot from this.

It disgusts me . . . but it works.

Comment: Although this works, someone else answered later and their solution seems more robust. I will leave this answer here though as it will work for versions that aren't Office365.